# query to append latest column/value of second table

Tags: sqlite

I'm building an ionic 2 App, where I store some local data via sqlite. I have 2 seperate tables called **history** and **favorites**.

my history table has the columns called 
id,answer,time 
and my favorites table 
id, likevalue, time.

I now want to query the last x rows of history and append the column likevalue by the same id from favorites by the latest likevalue of the same id, if there is no likevalue for the same id, it should be set as none or null.

If this is to complicated to understand, i will take the time to illustrate the problem by tables.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

solved it with a subquery

```
  SELECT h.*,
  (SELECT likevalue FROM favorites AS f WHERE h.id = f.id ORDER BY f.time DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS like
  FROM history AS h
  ORDER BY h.time DESC
  LIMIT ?,?
```